# Check if graph is Hamiltonian?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I am unable to determine whether the  graph below is Hamiltonian. Following a circuit 1-2-3-6-5-4-1 appears to make it a Hamiltonian graph. However the graph does not meet either Dirac's criteria or Ore's criteria.    I would request guidance on the ambiguity.

[image]

Comment: Those conditions are sufficient but not necessary for a hamilton-circuit. You solved it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you can show a circuit that visits every vertex once then returns to the first vertex - as you have here - you have proven that the graph is Hamiltonian.

Dirac's and Ore's theorems describe the threshold for graphs that have so many edges that they *must* be Hamiltonian, even without directly demonstrating a qualifying circuit. The threshold for those cases has to be high enough to ensure that the graph is [biconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_graph), i.e that cut-vertices and cut-edges are excluded (although biconnectedness alone does not guarantee a Hamiltonian circuit).